# Java If command

Tags: java, if-statement, command

I am trying to make it print if you type anything else than "BIF"

```
package del2;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class lilopg1 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        java.util.Scanner key = new java.util.Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("______");
        String f = key.next();
        System.out.println("______");

        // int s=Integer.parseInt(f);

        if (f.equals("bif")) {
            System.out.println("BIF FAN");
        }

         if Here is where I don't know what to put {System.out.println("Doesn't Seem like a FAN");}

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the Answer by NFE, and Niks Tyagi has showed, you Should to write:

```
if (f.equals("bif")) {
    System.out.println("BIF FAN");
} else {
    System.out.println("Doesn't Seem like a FAN");
}
```

But if you want to do the second part too with the if expression, you can write like following.

```
if (f.equals("bif")) {
    System.out.println("BIF FAN");
}

if(!f.equals("bif")){
    System.out.println("Doesn't Seem like a FAN");
}
```

But remember, that good programming practice is to use `if-else` whenever there are two possible conditions.

Answer (score 0):

You have to write `else condition`

```
  if (f.equals("bif")) {
      System.out.println("BIF FAN");
  } else {
      System.out.println("Doesn't Seem like a FAN");
  }
```

Refer to [if...else](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/if.html).

Additionally, the line "BIF FAN" should only be printed in case of BIF and not bif (that's what you  described in your task). At this moment the code accepts bif only in lower case.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to execute the code other than `if` then put it into `else` condition, like below :

```
if (f.equals("bif")) {
  System.out.println("BIF FAN");
} else {
  System.out.println("Doesn't Seem like a FAN");
}
```